# Why were the houseboats being confiscated?

Tags: plot-explanation, mud

In the movie Mud (2012), why were the houseboats by the Mississippi River being confiscated by the authorities?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mud_(2012_film) : "Ellis learns from his father that his parents are heading for divorce. This threatens their old river houseboat. Once no longer used as a residence by the owner, it will be removed."

Comment: Yes....but **why**. Under what law?